# How to count number of threads created in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have socket programming and for every client i'm creating new threads and using application with multithreads as in below.

```
fun ClientHandler() {
        try {
            var count = 0
            var serverSocket = ServerSocket(5000)

            while (true) {
                val socket: Socket = serverSocket!!.accept()
                count++
                socket.reuseAddress = true
                _log("${socket.remoteSocketAddress} Client Connected. Connected client count is $count")
                Thread(ServerThread(socket)).start() //Here i'm creating Threads. 
            }
        } catch (e: ConnectException) {
            _logEx("UnExpected connection error", e)
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            _logEx("ClientHandler", ex)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            _logEx("ServerSocketHandler ", e)
        }

}

internal inner class ServerThread(socket: Socket) : Runnable  {
    private val client: Socket = socket
    private val reader: Scanner = Scanner(client.getInputStream())
    private val writer = PrintStream(client.getOutputStream())
    private var receiveString: String = ""
    override fun run() {
        try {
            while(reader.hasNextLine()){
                receiveString = reader.nextLine() ?: ""
                _log("Message received: " + receiveString)
                if (receiveString != null && receiveString != "") {
                    checkMessage(receiveString, writer,client)
                }
            }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            _log("Cannot read the message. Please try again")
            //_log(ex.localizedMessage)
            val spReq = Error()
            spReq.sendErrorMsg(writer, "Cannot read the message. Please try again",client)
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**
I added ServerThread code part too.

How to follow them and get their statuses?

Comment: What do you mean by track them? checking periodically their status? check if they've been killed?

Comment: @DiegoMarcher yes i want to get their status?(alive or sleep or killed) and how many they are ?

Comment: Then I'd simply create a Map with all the threads that have been created for further reference

Comment: @DiegoMarcher can you give example . I'm new on Kotlin

Comment: I'll post it as answer

Comment: It doesn't sound like a good idea to watch threads, manage them manually and kill them if needed. You should implement your threads in a way that they handle themselves correctly. Although, it could make sense to track them for debugging purposes.

Comment: Hm....I'm not sure setting `reuseAddress` has any meaning for an *accepted* socket...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep track of the threads and their state by having a Map for further reference

```
fun ClientHandler() {
    try {
        var count = 0
        val serverSocket = ServerSocket(5000)

        while (true) {
            val socket: Socket = serverSocket.accept()
            count++
            socket.reuseAddress = true
            threads["thread name here"] = ServerThread(socket)
        }
    } catch (e: ConnectException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

fun stopServerThread(threadName: String) {
    threads[threadName]?.interrupt()
}

internal inner class ServerThread(private val client: Socket) : Thread()  {
    private val reader = Scanner(client.getInputStream())
    private val writer = PrintStream(client.getOutputStream())
    private var receiveString: String = ""
    
    init {
        start()
    }
    
    override fun run() {
        try {
            while(reader.hasNextLine()){
                if (isInterrupted) {
                    break
                }
                receiveString = reader.nextLine() ?: ""
                if (receiveString != "") {
                    checkMessage(receiveString, writer, client)
                }
            }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            _log("Cannot read the message. Please try again")
            //_log(ex.localizedMessage)
            val spReq = Error()
            spReq.sendErrorMsg(writer, "Cannot read the message. Please try again",client)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok but checkSocketThred should be runnable, right? You wrote as normal function.

Comment: it depends on where do you want to call it, you can perform this check in a separated thread, you can make the threads perform a self-check. I'm not sure what you want to achieve here...

Comment: I'm tryng to create thread and in that thread i'm opening socket receiving and sending message then closing socket... but thread keeps stay open and sleeping on app (I watched on Profiler Android studio) and i'm concern to blow up memory....

Comment: Can you post the ServerThread code content in the original question?

Comment: posted ServerThread

Comment: I tested this locally, I don't know what your checkMessage does but threads are being created and destroyed as soon as the run() method finished processing the input, if you need to explicitly kill the thread, I'll update the answer with that feature

Comment: My checkMessage is simple json actually i'm getting that json and send another json . Can you post detailed answer please?

Comment: I've updated the answer, I'd change the ServerThread to be an actual Thread (extend Thread class) and thus being able to stop it whenever it's needed

Comment: I appriciate for your effort thanks i will try